# Rails: How can i make image_tag use the fqdn?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I currently am using:

```
image_tag(src)
```

Which displays the image using the relative path. I would like to use the full path, but don't see how to do it from reading the docs.

Thanks!

edit:

Setting `ActionController::Base.asset_host` works for the application, but I also need it to work when sending an html mailer out via a rake task.  Any additional suggestions?

Comment: Updated my answer with the bit for emails, but you shouldn't be having any issues within rake tasks as long as you are A) loading the environment, B) setting the asset host for the given environment. I don't know why you would be generating HTML in your rake tasks, though (except for emails perhaps, which is easy [see answer]).

Comment: yea, i'm sending html emails. ActionMailer::Base.asset_host worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use the full path you need to let Rails know the absolute portion of the URL. You can do this by setting the asset host, though it's typically used to set a 3rd party asset host:

```
ActionController::Base.asset_host = 'www.example.com'
ActionMailer::Base.asset_host = 'www.example.com' # for emails
```

You would want to set this for each of your environments, so in `config/environments/development.rb` you might instead set 'www.yourapp.pow'.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
ActionMailer::Base.asset_host = '...'
```